# git clone from github cause :Permission denied (publickey). fatal: can't read remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm using Ubuntu and I want to clone my github repository while authenticating using ssh.
I generated a ssh key using the following command:

```
ssh-Keygen -t rsa -C “youEmail”
```

I also added the contends of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to my github ssh keys.

When I test this setup using `ssh -T git@github.com` the response is `Hi shouldnotappearcalm! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`.

When I attempt to clone my repository I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: cannot read remote repository。
```

Comment: Did you configure your `~/.ssh/config`-file?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you reload your bashrc file (for example) or restart your terminal ? :)

Comment: thanks，i find the phenomenon is caused by the sudo command,the sudo maybe equal use root but ,in root,it not have ssh config and id_rsa,i chmod the directory to +777,and i can clone and push,very thanks,it's really stupid question,and my write is not well,sorry